# Aparapi buffer values not copied

Tags: java, parallel-processing, opencl, aparapi

I get the following problem on `OpenCL platform` (running on Intel HD 4000), when i fill buffer inside kernel with values `buf[getGlobalId()] = getGlobalId()` some of the values are not copied back from Device to host. Instead of `[0, 1,2,3,4...]` sometimes i get `[0,0,0,3,4,...]`.

I tried adding `localBarrie`r at the end of kernel, and explicit buffer handling but it did't get expected results.
When I set execution mode to CPU everything works fine, does anybody know any reason for this behavior ?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code?